# Outline Button, how they affect UX?

Tags: gui-design, buttons, cta

With iOS 7 Apple used buttons with rounded rectangle borders (Outline Button).
But, Apple has moved away from buttons with rounded rectangle borders. Because they found that kind of buttons decreased the CTA.
What do you think about this? Do you have any case history to show or speak about?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a link to that research Apple carried out about the rounded button corners?

Comment: Hi Ivan, unfortunately right now I don't have with me that research.
I've seen that at the WMEXPO an important Italian Event about web marketing, I'm waiting in these days the slide about that event...

Answer (score 5):

Outline buttons (Ghost buttons) have a particularly clean, subtle look, work with almost any design. Some designers use them on elegant, sophisticated designs.

I like to use these buttons as secondary buttons. There’s no color fill so it won’t take attention away from the main action (for example like cancel buttons). In most cases, using outline button as a primary CTA isn’t a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Well... It depends on how you use these buttons. You have to be very careful, especially if you have images in the background. I like them when you have them in a light color on dark duotone backgrounds. And of course it depends on how you want to give more accent in your CTAs.

Comment: Of course... 
For the new website design that we're preparing, the outline button fits very well but I'm scared about decreasing the potentiality of the CTA.
And of course the CTR... 
Thank you for your reply! ;)